# CORS not working in standalone tomcat

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, tomcat, spring-boot

I am developing a web application in spring boot and I retrieve the data from the database and produce a Json list and send it to a url(Rest Web Services).Then I get it from a get request in the Javascript using getJSON.

```
$.getJSON(
  'http://localhost:8080/dataurl?i=1',
  function(data) {
   }
```

But it works fine with embedded tomcat server and does not work with standalone tomcat server.The error I get is

It is only returning a empty JSON array when I access the url in browser.

Why is it not working in standalone tomcat server.Is it also possible to add oauth2 security to this?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is an AJAX request. The request will be CORS if requires to load Cross Origin Resources ( simplifying served in other domain). Emdedded or standalone tomcat has nothing to do with CORS. Include the error traces  in the question so somebody could analyze them

Comment: There was a mapping problem.But now it returns an empty array each time.Do u have  any idea about why it is doing like that?

Comment: Without code or logs is not possible to say

Comment: I solved it.It was the postgresql jdbc maven dependency.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable CORS you should create filter.

```
@Component
public class CorsConfig implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsConfig.class);

public CorsConfig() {
    log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

This will add necessary headers for CORS.

Comment: where should I invoke this ?

Comment: You shouldn't, just add this class wherever you want. (In resonable folder with all your configuration classes. To keep project clean)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the with postgresql maven dependency.When I changed the dependency it worked.Hope it helps anyone